# PHP LDAP Authentication - With cookies?

Tags: php, authentication, cookies, ldap

I'm currently setting up PHP to use LDAP authentication, but looking to use cookies so that we don't have users logging in every time...

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to use cookies to authenticate with LDAP continually over a set period of time? (storing the password obviously being the main concern)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using adLDAP http://adldap.sourceforge.net/
Store in your database a token (phpsessid) when the auth is made with a timeout.
On every page create a check_session function that verify the phpsessid if it's still valid.

I implemented this last week and it works like a charm.

Hope this helps.